# How to access an object's fields and manipulate them when using pre_delete?

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals

I have a foreign key in the model and I want to change a field's value in that object when pre_delete is called. I'm new to this concept and just found out that you use a pre delete signal like this:

```py
@receiver(pre_delete, sender=MyModel)
def bid_deletion(sender, instance, using, **kwargs):
    pass
```

What should I write to use the foreign key object's field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `instance`, so:

```
@receiver(pre_delete, sender=MyModel)
def bid_deletion(sender, instance, using, **kwargs):
    item = instance.some_foreignkey
    item.field = some_value
    item.save()
```